# Adding strings to a combobox which is a member of CComboBoxEx

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc

I want to add an associated Icon along with each string to a combo box. I am using `CComboBox` class of MFC and as `CComboBox` dosent give me any option to set image list

I tried to use `CComboBoxEx` which is an extended class of `CComboBox` 
I created a control variable `m_cMyCombo` and tried to add strings and also set the image list.

I am doing `m_cMyCombo.AddString(_T("test"))` but it asserts. I am trying to add this in my `OnInitDialog()` and i am sure the control is been created already as it dosent giev me any problem in `DoDataExchange()`

What could be the issue ?

Comment: *"but it asserts"* - The expression that fails is important. You need to add both the assertion text as well as the source code that fails to your question. Assertions in MFC usually indicate an issue with client code (i.e. your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `AddString()` to add items to a `CComboBoxEx`. Instead, you should call [InsertItem()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5zbff3f.aspx#ccomboboxex__insertitem):

```
COMBOBOXEXITEM item = { 0 };
item.mask = CBEIF_TEXT;
item.iItem = 0;
item.pszText = L"Item 1";
m_comboEx.InsertItem(&item);
```

The `COMBOBOXEXITEM` structure will also let you set which image in the image list to use for this item.